# Screen within Another Screen

Tags: film-techniques, terminology

What do you call a filming technique of having a smaller screen within the main screen?  It's typically used in a news show where the main screen shows the report from the scene and the small one shows the news studio.

Comment: TV's have long had a functionality called "Picture In Picture" (or "PIP" for short), so I would imagine it's probably the same.

Comment: I guess you mean something like this http://www.studiobriefing.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Screen-shot-2011-02-03-at-12.44.52-PM.png I think it is simply called *superiposition* (see here: http://www.qsl.net/n2jac/jota2k/BROADCAST%20GLOSSARY.htm )

Comment: @mattiav27 Typo in your comment: "superimposition" needs an "m" in it. :)

Comment: Looks like e closest for what I was looking for is super-imp (cf. qsl).  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broad term is *[split screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_screen_%28filmmaking%29)*.

> In film and video production, split screen is the visible division of
>   the screen, traditionally in half, but also in several simultaneous
>   images, rupturing the illusion that the screen's frame is a seamless
>   view of reality, similar to that of the human eye.
>   [...]
>
> **In television**
>
> The split screen has also been used extensively in television
>   programs. Newscasts often show two reporters in a split screen frame.

Note that this is a really broad term.

For instance, in the context of visual effects, split screen is often used to describe a technique that allows an actor to appear twice in the same scene. This is often used to portray twins or doppelgangers in movies which are played by one actor but share some common scenes. Here it is of course required that the split remains invisible to the viewer for the effect to work.

Comment: A "split screen" is used when two objects/people are meant to share the entire frame.  Split screens run across the entire screen, either horizontally or vertically.  The OP is asking about one picture *inside* of another.  This is definitely not a split screen.

Comment: @JohnnyBones As I said, it's a broad term. If you simply mention split-screen, it's impossible to tell exactly how the different sub-images are arranged just from the term. Your definition of a split running across the entire screen, already contradicts many of the examples given by the linked Wikipedia article. There might be a more specific term for what was described in the original question, but split screen has the charm that in my experience it is widely understood even by people with little knowledge of filming techniques.